# How to render Dropdownlist with @razor inside a jQuery method - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, render

I am facing a strange problem ... I am unable to render razor via a dropdown within my javascript code ... he ends up losing because the quotes at render time. Following the do stretch code:

```
function AddNewRowPriceTable(tableName)
        {
            var trBegin = "<tr>";
            var trEnd = "</tr>";
            var tdBegin = "<td>";
            var tdEnd = "</td>";


            $("#" + tableName).append(trBegin + tdBegin + " @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.CompanyPriceType, DataDictionary.COMPANY_PRICE[ SessionWrapper.Culture ] ) " + tdEnd + trEnd);
    }
```

[image]
Here is the error I get, the values ​​of the drop down is "Cost" and "Revenue" does not have any special character. How to avoid this problem?

**UPDATE:** The problem is not in quotes, but the break lines when rendering, how can I avoid line breaks?

[image]

Comment: Use single quotes in your javascript, then it won't conflict.  alternatively, you could wrap that in a separate function and then replace the results of the function call, replacing quotes with single quotes in the returned string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had tried with single quotes also p error still persists ... you could give me an idea of how I can return the string value through another method?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch see my updates please.

Comment: Chances are, you will probably want to get the data dynamically anyways, so why not just make this an ajax call that will return the entire row?

Comment: Yes, this is a way out! Even had done, our friend @mo.esmp gave us a good solution and it apparently worked for me. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dropDown= '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.CompanyPriceType, DataDictionary.COMPANY_PRICE[ SessionWrapper.Culture ] )))';
$("#" + tableName).append(trBegin + tdBegin + dropdown + tdEnd + trEnd);
```

Comment: Yes, it really is a good solution! Many thanks for your help.